# FileNotFoundException occured in linux

Tags: java, linux, apache-poi, filenotfoundexception

I've placed "test.xls" file under following path in Linux

```
/usr/local/poi/template/test.xls
```

then, used this following java code to access the above xls file

```
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/usr/local/poi/template/test.xls");
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(in);
```

But when i run this code, i get only `FileNotFoundException`.

how can i fix it?

Comment: Is the file readable by the same user?  I.e. can you `cat /usr/local/poi/template/test.xls`?

Comment: Place the file into another place where it'll be accessable

Comment: This may sound silly - but is the file on the same machine as the code? Only I've seen cases where people had the same problem after forgetting that when deployed to a webapp server, their code could no longer see files on their development desktop!

Comment: it is now ok by moving this file to under "/var/local/poi/template/" instead of "/usr/local/poi/template/". But still don't get the reason why. I have set all same full permission to both path

Answer (score 0):

linux is case sensitive so make sure you spelled your path correctly. Additionally, the problem might be permission and you could be getting "access is denied". `chmod 777 fileName` should help with that.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible that either path `/usr/local/poi/template/test.xls` is not accessible or file itself is not accessible. You should make sure all directores `/usr/local/poi/template` are accessible by user who is running your java program and also file has `a+r` access mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be of file-path or permission issue.

1) Either you try to open the file using the same path from Command Prompt or try with cat command as `cat your current-file-path`.

2) Also try to list all file under that particular directory and see that if file exists or not.

Trying either this you can get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. check file path (look out for case, linux is case sensitive)
2. check the file permissions (you can modify permissions accordingly)
   -Permissions to the file has to be given to the user/user-group which is running the java process of your program.

for debugging purpose give the user who's running the program 777 on the file using `chmod`